# Trying to understand 'position' and 'z-index. Having an issue with my code

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, position, z-index

Hoping someone can give me a hand.

I am working on a website that requires some overlaying images with div in between but I can't seem to get the last bit right.

Currently my footer is not at the bottom of the page and is instead sticking to the the top of the previous div.

```
<div id="hillparent">

  <img id="orangehill" class="img-fluid" src="https://i.imgur.com/hntjB3B.png?1">

  <div id="lowerthird">
    <img id="lightbulb" class="img-fluid" src="/img/home/lightbulb.png">

  </div>

  <img id="pinkhill" class="img-fluid" src="https://i.imgur.com/ayGKiwy.png?1">

</div>





<footer>

  <div class="row text-center footerbutton">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary"><a href="#">Contact
        Us</a></button>
    <a href="#" class="btn-floating btn-lg btn-fb" role="button"><i
          class="fab fa-facebook-square"></i></a>
    <a href="#" class="btn-floating btn-lg btn-ins" role="button"><i
          class="fab fa-instagram-square"></i></a>
  </div>

</footer>
```

''

```
#lowerthird {
 background-color: #2e3f53;
}

#hillparent {
  position: relative;
}

#orangehill {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

#lowerthird {
  background-color: #2e3f53;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
}

#pinkhill {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 3;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

footer {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #000;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 3;
}
```

Here is the code pen: https://codepen.io/dylmcd/pen/XWXXmBX

I managed to get the hills working after a lot of trial and error with the div sitting in the middle that I am going to put content in. Here is a screen shot of what I want it to look like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PxhNN.jpg

Has anyone got any ideas of where I am going wrong. This is my first time dealing with z-index and positioning.

Thanks

Comment: did you try `footer{position:fixed;bottom:0;}`?  You have a relative path for your lightbulb image so it is not displaying in codepen.

Comment: Yeah, that just fixes the footer to the bottom of the viewport rather than the bottom of the entire page

Comment: You have all of the children of `#hillparent` positioned absolutely.  This removes them from the DOM structure and so `#hillparent` will have no height unless you set a fixed height.  The parent of an absolute positioned element cannot take the height of the child.  There are many discussions on this.  Therefore you won't be able to position the footer "naturally" (relatively) to the bottom of the `absolute` content since the next relative position in the DOM is still the top of the page.  You will either need to set a fixed height on `#hillparent` or be happy with the footer fixed to viewport